# Form created using wordpress plugin does not have bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a website in wordpress 4.2.2.

I created a plugin to customize the registration page. I activated my plugin and called my form function within wp-login.php like this

```
case 'register' :
    require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    custom_registration_function(); 
    login_footer('user_login');

break;
```

I can see my new registration form but the problem is, the wordpress styles are totally gone. So I have a plain HTML page with no styles. Wordpress is not loading bootstrap for this page.

I do not know why bootstrap is not being loaded.

Comment: Your WordPress styles maybe overriding the Bootstrap styles. What is the order in which the CSS scripts are present?

Comment: add enque style and script in your plugin file

Comment: I do not have any styles in my plugin. Can you tell me how to add enque style in my plugin? @vel

Comment: is form show admin page or client page?

Comment: It is the default registration page, wp-login. The url is wp-login.php?action=register.  After I made changes to this page then all the trouble started. Now I saw in chrome inspector that no styles are loaded @vel

Comment: you should register styles and script and theme functions.php file. so only styles loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can add css in plugin folder or you should register styles and script and theme functions.php file.

```
function myplugin_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'style-name',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_scripts' );
```